# SQL Query to avoid Duplicate IDs

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have Projects table & multiple task mapped with projects. If all of the tasks are completed in Project, then am trying to display YES. If tasks are not mapped i display NA. These two conditions are quite straight forward to do.

But if i have more than one task mapped with project A & if any one of the task is not completed, and all other task completed in that project A, i want to display NO.

i tried this query to get below o/p.

```
            SELECT DISTINCT PROJECT.[PROJ_ID],  
            CASE WHEN TASK_STA.TASK_STA_DS = 'Completed' THEN 'YES'  WHEN TASK_STA.TASK_STA_DS is null THEN 'NA' ELSE 'NO' END AS [Are all Tasks Completed]
            FROM PROJECT LEFT JOIN [PROJ_TASK] ON PROJECT.[PROJ_ID] = [PROJ_TASK].[PROJ_ID]
            LEFT JOIN dbo.TASK_STA
            ON [PROJ_TASK].TASK_STA_ID = TASK_STA.TASK_STA_ID

        PROJ_ID Completed
        20      NO
        20      YES
        21      NA
        22      YES
        24      NA
```

Is there any way to get o/p as below.

```
        PROJ_ID Completed
        20      NO
        21      NA
        22      YES
        24      NA
```

Comment: use group by PROJECT.[PROJ_ID]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a couple of extra left joins to filter out the unwanted condition. Working example:

```
DECLARE @PROJECT TABLE (PROJ_ID int)
DECLARE @PROJTASK TABLE (PROJ_ID int, TASK_STA_ID int)
DECLARE @TASK_STA TABLE (TASK_STA_ID int, TASK_STA_DS varchar(10))

INSERT INTO @PROJECT
(PROJ_ID)
VALUES(20),
(21),
(22),
(24)

INSERT INTO @PROJTASK
(PROJ_ID, TASK_STA_ID)
VALUES(20, 201),
(20, 202),
(22, 221)

INSERT INTO @TASK_STA
(TASK_STA_ID, TASK_STA_DS)
VALUES(201, 'NO'),
(202, 'Completed'),
(221, 'Completed')

SELECT 
DISTINCT 
p.[PROJ_ID],  
    CASE 
    WHEN ts.TASK_STA_DS = 'Completed' THEN 'YES'  
    WHEN ts.TASK_STA_DS is null THEN 'NA' 
    ELSE 'NO' END AS [Are all Tasks Completed]
FROM @PROJECT p 
    LEFT JOIN @PROJTASK pt ON p.[PROJ_ID] = pt.[PROJ_ID]
    LEFT JOIN @TASK_STA ts ON pt.TASK_STA_ID = ts.TASK_STA_ID 

SELECT 
DISTINCT 
    p.[PROJ_ID],  
    CASE 
    WHEN ts.TASK_STA_DS = 'Completed' THEN 'YES'  
    WHEN ts.TASK_STA_DS is null THEN 'NA' 
    ELSE 'NO' END AS [Are all Tasks Completed]
FROM @PROJECT p 
    LEFT JOIN @PROJTASK pt ON p.[PROJ_ID] = pt.[PROJ_ID]
    LEFT JOIN @TASK_STA ts ON pt.TASK_STA_ID = ts.TASK_STA_ID 
    LEFT JOIN @PROJTASK pt2 ON p.[PROJ_ID] = pt.[PROJ_ID] AND pt.TASK_STA_ID > pt2.TASK_STA_ID 
    LEFT JOIN @TASK_STA ts_NOs ON pt2.TASK_STA_ID = ts_NOs.TASK_STA_ID AND ts.TASK_STA_DS = 'Completed' AND ts_NOs.TASK_STA_DS != 'Completed'
WHERE ts_NOs.TASK_STA_ID IS NULL
```

This is the output

```
PROJ_ID Are all Tasks Completed
20  NO
21  NA
22  YES
24  NA
```

Comment: Thanks for your help..This is not fetching YES completed status.

Comment: Proj. 22 is a YES and it's showing. What project/task/status combination is not showing?

Answer (score 1):

You can use group_concat function for completed column.

Answer (score 1):

try this..........

```
    ;with cte as
  (
    SELECT  X.PROJECT.[PROJ_ID],X.[Are all Tasks Completed]
    FROM
    (
     SELECT DISTINCT PROJECT.[PROJ_ID],  
            CASE WHEN TASK_STA.TASK_STA_DS = 'Completed' THEN 'YES'  WHEN TASK_STA.TASK_STA_DS is null THEN 'NA' ELSE 'NO' END AS [Are all Tasks Completed]
            FROM PROJECT LEFT JOIN [PROJ_TASK] ON PROJECT.[PROJ_ID] = [PROJ_TASK].[PROJ_ID]
            LEFT JOIN dbo.TASK_STA
            ON [PROJ_TASK].TASK_STA_ID = TASK_STA.TASK_STA_ID
     ) X 
     GROUP BY X.PROJECT.[PROJ_ID],X.[Are all Tasks Completed]

    ) 

    select * from cte  a where a.[Are all Tasks Completed] = 'NO'  GROUP BY a.PROJECT.[PROJ_ID],a.[Are all Tasks Completed]
    union all
    select * from cte  b where  b.PROJECT.[PROJ_ID] not in ( select a.PROJECT.[PROJ_ID] from cte  a where a.[Are all Tasks Completed] = 'NO' )
            GROUP BY b.PROJECT.[PROJ_ID],b.[Are all Tasks Completed]
```

Comment: This is fetching only Project IDs with NO completed status.

Comment: @Saravanakumar:: Tanks for the comment...
Please check now i have changed the query ...